# Why sealed classes are not allowed to be generic type parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have:

```
public abstract class DbManager<ConnectionType>
    where ConnectionType : class, IDbConnection, new() {...}
```

now I have respectively:

```
public class Db2Manager : DbManager<iDB2Connection>      // OK, NO problem
public class OleDbManager : DbManager<OleDbConnection>   // OK, NO problem
public class SqlServerManager : DbManager<SqlConnection> // OK, NO problem
public class SsasManager : DbManager<AdomdConnection>    // NOK, YES, a PROBLEM!
```

Why this?
Because in the namespace Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient we have a **sealed** class:

```
// Assembly Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll, v2.0.50727
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;

namespace Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient
{
    public sealed class AdomdConnection : Component, IDbConnection, 
                                                     IDisposable, ICloneable
    {
        public AdomdConnection();
```

a) Why is it restricted to use a sealed class as a generic parameter (!*parameter*, not *constraint*!)?
b) How to workaround this?
c*) Was it a good idea to make that class sealed?

PS. Maybe you have a lot of reasons to consider that this generic DbManager is not a good idea, but, anyway, I would like just to understand if it is possible to workaround this sealed class in generic param... Thanks!

PPS. Error message:

> 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter in the generic type or method.

An other error message specifies:

> The type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection'
>   cannot be used as type parameter in the generic type or method there
>   is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from
>   'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection' to
>   'System.Data.IDbConnection'

`AdomdConnection` has a Parameterless Public constructor.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Is it possible there's another class by the same name in your scope that doesn't meet the criteria? Perhaps a different assembly version? I can't reproduce this locally.

Comment: "`AdomdConnection` has a Parameterless Public constructor." Double-check that please because I'd hate to think the compiler is lying.

Comment: @Ken: see my edits. I compiled the assembly in which I had `AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there's no such limitation on sealed classes. The following code compiles fine, so there is probably something else going on.

```
public abstract class DbManager<T> where T : class, IDbConnection, new()
{
}

public class ConcreteDbManagerUsingSealedClass : DbManager<MySealedConnection>
{
}

public sealed class MySealedConnection : IDbConnection
{
    public IDbTransaction BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel il)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IDbTransaction BeginTransaction()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ChangeDatabase(string databaseName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public int ConnectionTimeout
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public IDbCommand CreateCommand()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string Database
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ConnectionState State
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I compiles also with `public class ConcreteDbManagerUsingAdomdConnectionClass : DbManager<AdomdConnection>`... mistery...

Comment: also I have another one: The type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection' cannot be used as type parameter in the generic type or method there is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection' to 'System.Data.IDbConnection'

Comment: Based also on this one  "// Assembly Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll, v2.0.50727" is it possible that you're mixing .NET 2 and .NET 4 and some strange things are happening because of that?... perhaps the Adodm stuff is built againt IDbConnection of .NET 2 and the rest of your code is .NET 4 ?

Comment: I don't know what was wrong, but I should add a reference to that assembly(AdomdClient) to another project (using my generic class) in my solution in order to get it work.... Thanks!

Comment: Ah, you were missing some dependencies then. I have a similar weird situation sometimes when (if I recall correctly) try to do a using (someDisposable) { } but I have not referenced System.Core.dll or System.dll in my project references... or something like that.